# How to set the value of a select field through htmlAttribute in MVC 5?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, actionlink, html.actionlink

I have an ActionLink defined as in this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Write a review", "Create", "Reviews")
```

The point is that, when it redirects to the Create view of the Reviews controller, there is a select field with the id of BusinessID. Therefore, I want to set the value of the select field to the specific entry when it opens the page. Let's say that the value that I want to set it is Picasso. How, can I achieve it? Is it possible to do it somehow using htmlAttributes?

Comment: If you have select html in your redirected page, can't you just set option field to 'selected'? Something like this: `<select> <option value = 'Picasso' selected> Picasso </option> </select>`?

Comment: Or if I understand you correctly, you want to set `<select>` tag in your Create.chtml according your ActionLink? In that case you can accept parameter in your Create action of ReviewsController, and then use object routeValues of `@Html.ActionLink` to send particular Id you want to be set as selected. Something like this: `@Html.ActionLink("Write a review", "Create", "Reviews", new {id = 1}, null);` then your Create action accepts this Id (e.g. `ActionResult Create(id) { return View(id) }`) and renders Create.chtml accordingly selected item.

Comment: @ShukhratRaimov Yes, I want the second option. Though I guess I need to provide a selected attribute in DropDownLink.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accept id parameter of your selected item in your **Create** action method of **ReviewsController**, and then use **object routeValues** parameter of **@Html.ActionLink()** to send particular id you want to be set as selected. Something like this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Write a review", "Create", "Reviews", new {id = 1}, null);
```

then your **Create** action method should accept this **id** (e.g:

```
  public ActionResult Create(int id) 
  { 
      List<SelectListItem> items = new List<SelectListItem>(); //create <option> </option> items of DropDownList
      items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "da Vinci", Value = "0", Selected = (id == 0)});
      items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Picasso", Value = "1", Selected = (id == 1)});
      items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "van Gogh", Value = "2", Selected = (id == 2)});
      ViewBag.Painters = items;
      return View();
   }
```

which renders **Create.chtml** accordingly selected item:

```
@Html.DropDownList("Painters")
```

Note that `DropDownList` parameter`("Painters")` should have the same name as a `ViewBag.Painters`. As a result after clicking a link you will get selected item to Picasso, because it is `Selected` attribute will be true, as we have assigned it in Create action method.

I think there could be smarter way to write this dropdownlist, but this action method works fine. I encourage you to read more about @Html.DropDownList helper method on the following links: [www.asp.net](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/javascript/working-with-the-dropdownlist-box-and-jquery/using-the-dropdownlist-helper-with-aspnet-mvc) and [K.Scott Allen](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2013/03/11/dropdownlistfor-with-asp-net-mvc.aspx). Hope you can find this helpful.